# Is it possible to use Core ML models in Xcode playground?

Tags: swift-playground, xcode9-beta, swift4, coreml

Now i am working on application that is using `CoreML` models to detect some data probability.

But i would like to know is it possible to use `CoreML` models in Xcode playground, because it will be more convinient for testing purposes.

I try to add models to Xcode 9 playground but there is no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic generation of Swift (or ObjC) classes for Core ML models is an extra build step, so it requires a full Xcode project. (Getting that in playgrounds would be a great [feature request to send to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).)

It should still be possible in playgrounds to load models as bundle resources and evaluate them using the more general [`MLModel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel) API. Or to copy-paste the generated Swift code for a model from a project into a playground.